# req.baseUrl is empty

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building an Express API, the API endpoint is `GET /tasks/:id`. I need to use `req.baseUrl`. It should contain '/tasks' in this case, but it's empty.

Printing out the `req` object shows that `req.originalUrl` is correct but `req.baseUrl` is an empty string:

```
...
baseUrl: '',
originalUrl: '/tasks/608aa21aac412401305ba105',
...
```

What could be causing this? I could extract the baseUrl from the originalUrl but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

Comment: Can you show us how you mounting this route? I'm talking about app.use(<your-route>).

Comment: @gregooroo I used the same structure used in this project here: https://github.com/makinhs/rest-api-tutorial see the index.js file and routes files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer above that you're using the same structure like [this here](https://github.com/makinhs/rest-api-tutorial), it make sense that `req.baseUrl` is empty. Why? Let't check the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl)

> req.baseUrl - The URL path on which a router instance was mounted.

Since your project doesn't involve any route mounting it's ok that you see empty string. Take a look at `users/routes.config.js`. Routes there are configured with .get. post etc and then this function is being executed inside index.js file - no `app.use` (mounting) involved. Compare this to the example presented in the docs.